# Custom pager outside of kendo-grid

Tags: kendo-ui-angular2

I want to place grid pager component outside of grid. Can I use `PagerComponent` of the `GridModule` or should I do it myself?. Actually I want to use that pager for multiple views. One of them will be kendo-grid.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `PagerComponent` is not intended for using outside the `GridComponent` at the moment.

However you can suggest this in the [Feedback portal](http://kendoui-feedback.telerik.com/forums/555517-kendo-ui-for-angular-2-feedback).